# How to use ionic default colors programmatically?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I can use ionic default colors like primary, success, danger etc in CSS by typing `var(--ion-color-primary)`. But I want to use them in typescript and can't find any way to access them programmatically.

Comment: why you want to use them in typeScript? what is your scenario exactly?

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Actually I can use them by manually writing hex codes as well. And that's what I'm doing right now. But I was wondering if there's any way to use them by there names.

Comment: you can use style attribute on your element. r.g: `[ngStyle]="{color: yourCondition == tue ? 'var(--ion-color-primary)' : 'var(--ion-color-danger)' }"` something like this.